# What is the difference between WINDOWCLOSE event type and QUIT event type

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, pygame2

I've been wondering what is the difference between this two, I saw `WINDOWCLOSE` in the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) but it doesn't have much information on it, so can someone tell me what is the difference between this two?

Comment: Window close doesn't end application If you have multiple windows, just closes that window, but quit event completely end the application.

Comment: Ah ok so if 1 window has been closed it will trigger this event but it doesn't end the application because there may be another window that is opened in the application, thanks!

Comment: @hamed_gibago can you put your response in an answer so it can be accepted and help the community?

Comment: Sure. Thank you for acceptance and mention that want to make it accepted. I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window close doesn't end application If you have multiple windows, just closes that window, but quit event completely end the application.